# Transferring files through wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, android, file-transfer, wifi-configuration

I have an android phone and a laptop (windows 8 Pro). Can I transfer files through wi-fi (not bluetooth), if yes, how ? And what are the steps for sharing files between to laptops through wi-fi ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done easily via SMB.

Assuming you have a Windows 7/8 laptop, you can share a folder by right clicking the folder -> select properties -> change to the Sharing tab -> click "Share". Make the folder available to the LAN. It can be visible to "Everyone" (Anonymous) or to specific users on your network if they are set up.

On the Android side, you can use an application like ES File Explorer that supports SMB network shares. Change view to LAN. Select New Server.  For the server you use the IP Address or Computer Name of the laptop along with the name of the shared folder. Example "192.168.1.100/My Documents"

You may have to supply the credentials that you use to log in to the computer if you chose to only make the folder available to specific user accounts.

Files can be transferred from the Android interface in both directions this way.

The instructions vary slightly with different Operating Systems and applications.

Comment: I have windows 8, will it make any difference ? And how to share files between two laptops (one windows 8 and other windows 7), and what will be the transfer rate.

Comment: Windows 8 is nearly identical to Windows 7 when sharing folders over a LAN. If I remember correctly as long as the 2 computers are on the same Workgroup or Domain, you will be able to find them in the Network View. (Open Start Menu -> Type "Network" -> Select Network.) In order for this to work you may have to enable File & Print Sharing. (Right click the Network Icon in the Notification Area/System Tray -> Select Network and Sharing Center -> Click Change Advanced Sharing Settings on the left and make sure it is enabled.

Comment: The transfer rate depends on the router and protocol being used. Generally the theoretical transfer speed is 54Mbps which translates to 6.75 Megabytes per second. In real life, transfer speeds will max out around 4 Megabytes per second. It depends greatly on traffic, interference, hardware, etc.

Comment: Is there any other way than a 3rd party app?